# Correct way to serialize datatable

Tags: c#, json, datatable, json.net

The following code gives an error on the last line `Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.`

```
DataTable dt = GetTable();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.None);
var @object = JObject.Parse(json);
```

What is the correct way to serialize the datatable to allow the line `var @object = JObject.Parse(json);` to work correctly?

Comment: What data are you passing in that could cause the error? What does `json` look like from the second line?

Comment: I used the first DataTable example here to test http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is json you get from the second line:

```
[
  {
    "Dosage": 25,
    "Drug": "Indocin",
    "Patient": "David",
    "Date": "2014-10-31T16:25:33.181239"
  },
  {
    "Dosage": 50,
    "Drug": "Enebrel",
    "Patient": "Sam",
    "Date": "2014-10-31T16:25:33.181239"
  },
  .....
```

Notice the first character, a `[`. That means it's an array, and *not an object*. That's the big keyword.

So, use this:

```
DataTable dt = GetTable();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.None);
var @object = JArray.Parse(json); // <-- Using JArray, not JObject
```

If you want to turn the json string back into a datatable, you can use this line:

```
var dataTable2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
```